# no suitable driver found calling getConnection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection, driver

I'm using MySQL 5.5 with its defaults. I created a user/password and ran a script creating a database called employees. Through the command prompt I can access the database:

```
mysql -u user -p
SELECT * FROM employees
```

In my Java application, I am unable to connect. I have tried these URLs, as well as others, but nothing works:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees" "user" "password"
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees" "user" "password"
"jdbc:mysql:///employees?user=user&password=password"
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
public Main()
{
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        //connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        // I don't know what else to try
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.print(ex + "\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the JDBC driver?  You haven't mentioned anything about getting it. http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: It it says no suitable driver found then your jdbc driver is not there is the classpath. If you are running this in application server then you might need to add the driver to your lib directory.

Comment: thank you, that solved my problem! I had downloaded it before, but it looked like it was out of date, so I didn't try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have Mysql driver jar in the class path and check MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html

Answer (score 0):

The error tells me that either

- [ConnectorJ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-installing.html) driver is not in your classpath. 
  OR
- When using DriverManager, the jdbc.drivers system property has not been populated with the location of the Connector/J driver.
  OR
- The format of your connection URL is incorrect, or you are referencing the wrong JDBC driver.
  In your scenario, it is the list item #1 which is the cause of the issue you are facing.

I would use something like below code snippet to get the connection object.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

Connection conn = null;
...
try {
conn =
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees?" +
                               "user=user&password=password");

 // Do something with the Connection

 ...
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
// handle any errors
System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
```